# How to use template literals queried from database or variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, string, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I have HTML e-mail templates stored in a MySQL database. Most of them include JavaScript variables. I tried to store them using template literals (i.e.: `${this.auth.user.name}`) but this will not return the variable but the exact string. I assume my problem is because the string is encapsulated by double quotes or single quotes and not back-ticks.

So my JavaScript looks the following, where `template` is an array of objects queried from my MySQL show here.

`var email_template: this.template[0].body;`

> The actual output is Hello ${this.auth.name}!

I expect the output of Hello Jack!

Do you have any ideas what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Tibor

Comment: If you're pulling something from a DB, it isn't a template literal. Please do not use `new Function` or `eval` or else you're opening up a massive security hole in your application, unless you parse and validate the template fully first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a `new Function` like so:

```js
const name = "Jack";
const string = "Hello ${name}";
const actualString = new Function("return `" + string + "`").call(string);
console.log(actualString);
```